# Grouping Rows in pandas as per the given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like shown:

```
    date        close   Target  Loss
34  17-08-2021  1543.95 0       0
35  18-08-2021  1740.6  1       0
36  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
37  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
38  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
39  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
40  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
41  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
42  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
43  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
44  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
45  18-08-2021  1740.6  0       0
58  20-08-2021  873.6   0       1
59  20-08-2021  881.05  0       0
60  20-08-2021  864.05  0       1 
61  23-08-2021  928.35  1       0
62  23-08-2021  921.65  0       0
63  23-08-2021  813.8   0       1
```

Now I want to use groupby to group all the values in the dataframe wherein the rows under the Target or Loss column is 1. But I need to preserve the row order. What I mean by this is that in the final Dataframe row no 35 should be the starting row followed by row no 58,60,61,63.The final Dataframe should look as shown:

```
    date        close   Satisfied
35  18-08-2021  1740.6  1
58  20-08-2021  873.6   1
60  20-08-2021  864.05  1
61  23-08-2021  928.35  1
63  23-08-2021  813.8   1
```

The reason I am concerned with the order is because I have to calculate profit/Loss which can be obtained by subtracting the close values in resultant dataframe which can be acheived using diff method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `loc` and `pop`:

```
>>> df = df.loc[df[['Target', 'Loss']].eq(1).any(1)]
>>> df['Satisfied'] = df.pop('Target') + df.pop('Loss')
>>> df
          date    close  Satisfied
35  18-08-2021  1740.60          1
58  20-08-2021   873.60          1
60  20-08-2021   864.05          1
61  23-08-2021   928.35          1
63  23-08-2021   813.80          1
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

First sum columns and then filter by greate or equal by `1` should be simpliest solution here:

```
df['Satisfied'] = df.pop('Target') + df.pop('Loss')
df = df[df['Satisfied'].ge(1)]
print (df)
          date    close  Satisfied
35  18-08-2021  1740.60          1
58  20-08-2021   873.60          1
60  20-08-2021   864.05          1
61  23-08-2021   928.35          1
63  23-08-2021   813.80          1
```

If need alwyas `1` in `Satisfied` and possible `1` in both columns:

```
print (df.head())
          date    close  Target  Loss
34  17-08-2021  1543.95       0     0
35  18-08-2021  1740.60       1     1 <- changed sample
36  18-08-2021  1740.60       0     0
37  18-08-2021  1740.60       0     0
38  18-08-2021  1740.60       0     0


df['Satisfied'] = (df.pop('Target') + df.pop('Loss')).clip(upper=1)

df = df[df['Satisfied'].eq(1)]
print (df)
          date    close  Satisfied
35  18-08-2021  1740.60          1
58  20-08-2021   873.60          1
60  20-08-2021   864.05          1
61  23-08-2021   928.35          1
63  23-08-2021   813.80          1
```